# Typescript - Document what type options mean

Tags: typescript, document

I'm writing a wrapper for an API with typescript and some routes use a filter that uses numbers to represent different things:

0 = none, 1 = minimal, 2 = status

I would like to somehow document within typescript what 0, 1 and 2 represent but can't seem to find a way. I've tried this without luck

```
async getServerCount( filter?: 0|1|2 /* 0 = none, 1 = minimal, 2 = status*/)
```

Comment: consider using enums

Comment: If you can modify the server api, the better practice is to receive those values from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an enum

```
enum FilterType {
  NONE = 0,
  MINIMAL = 1,
  STATUS = 2
}
async getServerCount( filter?: FilterType );
```

and then to use it

```
getServerCount( FilterType.NONE );
```